# Unknown column in 'where clause' when using an alias for a subquery in MySQL

Tags: mysql, where, alias

This simple query:

```
select exam.id as exam_id,
(select count(*) from dataset where dataset.id = exam.id) as n_dataset
from exam
where n_dataset = 0
```

returns the following error:

```
ERROR 1054 (42S22) at line 1: Unknown column 'n_dataset' in 'where clause'
```

Why?

Comment: You can't call a field twice in this way. Can you give sample of your data ?

Comment: You should consider the `COALESCE(...)` function with your accepted [answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/283253/34007) - makes for nicer presentation!

Comment: Related to https://stackoverflow.com/q/153598/6064933

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the [order of operations](https://www.eversql.com/sql-order-of-operations-sql-query-order-of-execution/) with the `WHERE` clause is applied first before the `SELECT` operator. So `n_dataset` doesn't exist yet when the `WHERE` clause is being applied.

You would need to use `COUNT()` as a [window function](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-window-functions/) (version of MySQL depending, you should update your tags to include the version) to get the results you're looking for.

Or you can create your `COUNT()` query in a CTE first, then re-join to your table later on.

But interpreting your logic further, it sounds like your actual end goal is to get all `exams` that don't have any correlating `datasets`. You can accomplish that a lot simpler with a `LEFT JOIN` this way:

```
select distinct exam.id as exam_id, 0 as n_dataset
from exam
left join dataset
    on exam.id = dataset.id
where dataset.id is null
```

Comment: See my comment to the OP above - HTH!

Answer (score 2):

You can use simply HAVING in MySQL

> ```
> CREATE TABLE exam ( id int)
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE dataset ( id int)
> ```

> ```
> select exam.id as exam_id,
> (select count(*) from dataset where dataset.id = exam.id) as n_dataset
> from exam
> HAVING n_dataset = 0
> ```

> ```
> exam_id | n_dataset
> ------: | --------:
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ce65239537396db2a5a6c8ba879a5d9e)*